# Can't remove redirect malware on firefox

Tags: firefox, malware

I researched and found:

`mypageresults.com` is tabbed as a redirect virus that always slips into computer without user's approval.

I can't remove it.I deleted all files of firefox.I removed firefox and installed again,I did reset firefox.but still this problem is not solved.What should I do ?

and it is my etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   schwappkopf

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1 productsearch.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: Where did you find this? What is the actual problem you have? Please [edit] your question and add some more details.

Comment: "without user's approval." are you saying you did not install it? (by installing a plugin). Does this also happen with chromium? (if not: it is something in FF; if it does check your /etc/hosts)

Comment: is there anything weird in your plugins/extensions ? I don't know if all plugin directories get removed when you `apt-get purge firefox`

Comment: I dont have any plugin after re-installation.

Comment: download an anti virus and scan http://www.linux.org/threads/malware-and-antivirus-systems-for-linux.4455/

Comment: I downloaded comodo and scanned , found nothing..

Comment: Is schwappkopf a server? Have you checked in the server settings and code file areas?

Comment: nope it is not a server , it is me.

Comment: @tea-addict when replying to a user, please use the `@username` for example `@Fisher` so that I get a notification that you replied to me

Answer (score 0):

you have to purge firefox not just remove

```
sudo apt-get purge firefox
```

Delete the `.mozilla` directory from your home

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.mozilla
```

Now install firefox again.

Comment: thank you, but I did it.And it didn't work.Still same :/

Answer (score 0):

The last line in your hosts file does not appear in mine. Can anyone else confirm it's a legitimate entry? If not, try commenting it out with a "#" in front of the line. Good luck, YMMV.

```
#127.0.0.1 productsearch.ubuntu.com
```